# webpack2 dynamic style file require

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

I am working with webpack 2 and I want to include some style file that depends from different NODE_ENV.

I did something like this:

```
const stylesEntryName = process.env.SECOND_CLIENT ? "main_for_second_client" : "main";
const entryUrl = `assets/styles/${stylesEntryName}.styl`;


console.log("stylesEntryName ====>>> ", stylesEntryName, entryUrl);


require(entryUrl);
```

But it isn't working somehow. I have got an error: **Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

the console shows: *stylesEntryName ====>>>  main assets/styles/main.styl*

Maybe I do something wrong? (in case of direct url)

```
require('assets/styles/main.styl');
```

the code working fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

webpack is emitting that warning about the line `require(entryUrl)` because the value of the entryUrl variable is unknown until the code is executed (i.e., the require is not statically analyzable). Here's the webpack documentation about that: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#critical-dependencies

You can fix this problem by removing the dynamic require, and instead use if-else statements to pick a static require statement out of the possible choices. Here's code that does that for your issue:

```
if (process.env.SECOND_CLIENT === 'main_for_second_client') {
  require('assets/styles/main_for_second_client.styl')
} else {
  require('assets/styles/main.styl')
}
```